# How to auto resize JFrame according to content

Tags: swing, jframe, resize, dynamic-resizing

I have created a custom `JPanel` that displays images (lets call it `MyPanel`), I have added this to `JFrame`'s contentPane.

I want `JFrame` to be resized automatically to fit the `MyPanel` when image changes.

It looks like I need to call `frame.pack()` to do this. Calling `pack()` from `MyPanel` increases coupling so I don't want to do that.

To solve the issue I extended `JFrame` (lets call it `MyFrame`) and made `MyFrame` observer, and `MyPanel` observable. Whenever the image `MyPanel` is displaying changes it notifies the listeners, `MyFrame` for this instance. And then `MyFrame` calls `pack()` when it gets the notification.

Is there a smoother way of resizing `JFrame` according to its content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution you described seem reasonable.

Alternatively, whenever MyPanel changes its image, it can go find its parent Frame and then call pack() on it. If no such Frame exists, then don't do anything. No need to create additional classes, and its as loose a coupling as you are going to get. You can use [SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass%28java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component%29) to do this easily.

Comment: Yeah, my approach was reasonable. Thanks for approval :)